# Error while applying to_date() and add_months function in Spark SQL

Tags: sql, apache-spark, hive, apache-spark-sql

I am having following hive table. Column `cycle_month` has values in YYYYMM format.

```
+---------------+--------------+------------+
| column_value  | metric_name  |cycle_month |
+---------------+--------------+------------+
| A37B          | Mean         | 202005     |
| ACCOUNT_ID    | Mean         | 202005     |
| ANB_200       | Mean         | 202005     |
| ANB_201       | Mean         | 202006     |
| AS82_RE       | Mean         | 202006     |
| ATTR001       | Mean         | 202007     |
| ATTR001_RE    | Mean         | 202007     |
| ATTR002       | Mean         | 202008     |
| ATTR002_RE    | Mean         | 202008     |
| ATTR003       | Mean         | 202009     |
| ATTR004       | Mean         | 202009     |
| ATTR005       | Mean         | 202009     |
| ATTR006       | Mean         | 202010     |
```

I need to write a dynamic query to get values between user passed cycle_month value and cycle_month - 4 months.

Spark SQL Query:

```
select column_name, metric_name from table where cycle_month between add_months(to_date(202010,'YYYYMM'),-4) and 202010
```

Getting error

> [Error 10015]: Line 1:323 Arguments length mismatch ''YYYYMM'': to_date() requires 1 argument, got 2 (state=21000,code=10015)

Expected output:

```
+---------------+--------------+------------+
| column_value  | metric_name  |cycle_month |
+---------------+--------------+------------+
| ANB_201       | Mean         | 202006     |
| AS82_RE       | Mean         | 202006     |
| ATTR001       | Mean         | 202007     |
| ATTR001_RE    | Mean         | 202007     |
| ATTR002       | Mean         | 202008     |
| ATTR002_RE    | Mean         | 202008     |
| ATTR003       | Mean         | 202009     |
| ATTR004       | Mean         | 202009     |
| ATTR005       | Mean         | 202009     |
| ATTR006       | Mean         | 202010     |
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`Y` is not the correct format for year; it should be `y`. You should use `yyyyMM`. See https://spark.apache.org/docs/latest/sql-ref-datetime-pattern.html for details.

```
SELECT 
    column_name, metric_name, cycle_month
FROM 
    table
WHERE 
    to_date(cycle_month, 'yyyyMM') BETWEEN 
        add_months(to_date(202010, 'yyyyMM'), -4)
            AND 
        to_date(202010, 'yyyyMM')
```

Answer (score 1):

[**`to_date`**](https://spark.apache.org/docs/3.0.0-preview/api/sql/#to_date) function expects string as input and returns `date` to change date to `YYYYMM` use **`date_format`** function finally cast the **`date`** to **`int`**.

**`Try with this query`**

```
select column_name, metric_name from table where cycle_month between int(date_format(add_months(to_date('202010','YYYYMM'),-4),'YYYYMM')) and 202010
```

---

**`UPDATE:`**

```
sql("select int(date_format(add_months(to_date('202010','YYYYMM'),-4),'YYYYMM'))").show()
#+------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------+
#|CAST(date_format(CAST(add_months(to_date('202010', 'YYYYMM'), -4) AS TIMESTAMP), YYYYMM) AS INT)|
#+------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------+
#|                                                                                          201908|
#+------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------+
```

Comment: This still gives the same error because the date format is wrong - it should be `yyyyMM`, not `YYYYMM`

Comment: @mck, FYI It won't throw error if u specify `YYYYMM` Y is `week of the year`. in question author mentioned `Y` we can't blindly assume `y` and also please **execute commands before you post comment/downvote** **(Check my update section of the answer)**.

Comment: The command in the update section gives an error in Spark 3.0.0: `org.apache.spark.SparkUpgradeException: You may get a different result due to the upgrading of Spark 3.0: Fail to recognize 'YYYYMM' pattern in the DateTimeFormatter. 1) You can set spark.sql.legacy.timeParserPolicy to LEGACY to restore the behavior before Spark 3.0. 2) You can form a valid datetime pattern with the guide from https://spark.apache.org/docs/latest/sql-ref-datetime-pattern.html`

Comment: Also I presume in 99.99% of the cases `y` is what the user wants, not week of the year.

Comment: Both the answers works for me :) I am using Spark 2.4.0